# jQuery multilevel crossbrowser dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, menu, cross-browser, drop-down-menu

I've been testing lots of dropdown menus, but I was looking for some specific stuff:

- multilevel
- crossbrowser
- css based (mainly)
- if uses javascript, to be jQuery compatible
- easy to implement

After discarding some menus, I arrived to Superfish
http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

I had to discard it too, because the z-index fix for IE didn't work for me

**So, does any1 know about one good multilevel dropdown crossbrowser menu?**
Thanks

Comment: the best dropdown menu is the one you develop your self. All the rest are just, well, examples!